# Block import crashes on block where authorities have changed

Tags: block-import

We recently upgraded our chain from substrate V3 to `polkadot-0.9.24`. When we try to sync a node from 0, the block import fails on the first block where the authorities were changes (some block creator was added at that point). We are using `aura` consensus.

output of our node:

```
2022-09-23 13:26:18 ⚙️  Syncing 22.0 bps, target=#2446795 (5 peers), best: #112556 (0xca60…3cc9), finalized #112128 (0x1dcd…ad78), ⬇ 13.1kiB/s ⬆ 2.8kiB/s    
2022-09-23 13:26:23 ⚙️  Syncing 21.2 bps, target=#2446795 (5 peers), best: #112662 (0x345f…5f0e), finalized #112640 (0x3c2b…c601), ⬇ 13.1kiB/s ⬆ 2.5kiB/s    
2022-09-23 13:26:28 ⚙️  Syncing 22.6 bps, target=#2446796 (5 peers), best: #112775 (0x470d…c04a), finalized #112640 (0x3c2b…c601), ⬇ 12.8kiB/s ⬆ 1.2kiB/s    
2022-09-23 13:26:33 ⚙️  Syncing 22.2 bps, target=#2446797 (5 peers), best: #112886 (0x5742…1446), finalized #112640 (0x3c2b…c601), ⬇ 25.1kiB/s ⬆ 7.0kiB/s    
2022-09-23 13:26:38 ⚙️  Syncing 22.2 bps, target=#2446798 (5 peers), best: #112997 (0x169a…ab2a), finalized #112640 (0x3c2b…c601), ⬇ 14.1kiB/s ⬆ 2.0kiB/s    
2022-09-23 13:26:43 ⚙️  Syncing 22.8 bps, target=#2446799 (5 peers), best: #113111 (0xb42d…1792), finalized #112640 (0x3c2b…c601), ⬇ 14.8kiB/s ⬆ 2.3kiB/s    
2022-09-23 13:26:48 ⚙️  Syncing 22.6 bps, target=#2446800 (5 peers), best: #113224 (0x41a5…a8fc), finalized #113152 (0x5062…70ed), ⬇ 12.4kiB/s ⬆ 2.7kiB/s    
2022-09-23 13:26:50  Verification failed for block 0xa06d1231c7ad3403216a427883e18bccc95e461c902ff430f13543ce7c11f5d3 received from peer: 12D3KooWQ5zzNP458fPfY2eAEDaXsxPsLMNSd73D2ywJWMznHBDu, "Bad signature on 0xa06d1231c7ad3403216a427883e18bccc95e461c902ff430f13543ce7c11f5d3"    
2022-09-23 13:26:50  Error importing block 0x43907aee965aa2455ce149bb1565aeaa8370d0aa496472f0de55ffd7375f0338: block has an unknown parent    
2022-09-23 13:26:50  Error importing block 0xe2ffa1d2f46c777828ee6b0bb4b37d0f250bffb3fc9bba3fc2801c528c3c95c6: block has an unknown parent    
2022-09-23 13:26:50  Error importing block 0x322cd39b6d55fd9da9d9f603e1847c17c4c53d3e0b2d930584b2a9c9b3b0a246: block has an unknown parent
```

At block `0xa06d1231c7ad3403216a427883e18bccc95e461c902ff430f13543ce7c11f5d3` we went from 2 blockcreators to 3 blockcreators. We went digging in the aura consensus client and we believe the issue comes from:

https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/397da2753081b3cbe4cbb0893f17b4188f0d5997/client/consensus/aura/src/import_queue.rs#L83

It tries to get the author for this block to verify the signature but this seems to be failing somehow. Either it does not fetch the right author or the verification of the signature has changed?

Comment: Does the syncing process get stuck? IIUC, these are some fork blocks that you could ignore them.

Comment: Yes, the syncing process gets stuck after seeing that error. It drops all the peers and stops syncing. I'm trying to follow this now: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/issues/10103#issuecomment-1256102788

Comment: I narrowed down the issue in https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/issues/10103#issuecomment-1256449790